# Hive - empty string not kept

Tags: string, hive, null, is-empty

When I insert data containing an empty string in a tableA, and then perform a

```
select * from tableA;
```

I see that the empty string are replaced by NULL value.

How can i keep the empty string values instead of having the NULL values ?

Comment: share the ddl for your table, `show create table tableA` and show us how are you inserting records

Answer (score 0):

you should get empty string not null.

```
hive> create temporary table t1 as select '' as c1, 
' ' as c2; --- ' ' space
Time taken: 0.145 seconds, Fetched: 1 row(s)
hive> select concat('|',c1, '|', c2, '|') from t1;
OK
|| |
Time taken: 0.319 seconds, Fetched: 1 row(s)

hive> insert into t1 values ('  ', '   '); -- multiple spaces
Time taken: 13.6 seconds
hive> select concat('|',c1, '|', c2, '|') from t1;
OK
|| |
|  |   |
Time taken: 0.136 seconds, Fetched: 2 row(s)
```

Answer (score 0):

just discovered it ... The reason is that when the insert is done with empty value in a field that expects a string then the empty value is kept, but when the field expects something other than a string, for example if the field expects to receive an integer then the empty value is inserted as NULL value.